# How to check the upsell products stock and status in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, stock-status, up-sells

I need to check whether the upsell product is enabled or not and also check whether it is in stock or not in **Magento 2**. Please provide me a solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$currentProduct = $coreRegistry->registry('current_product');

if ($currentProduct) {

    $upSellProducts = $currentProduct->getUpSellProducts();

    if (!empty($upSellProducts)) {
        foreach ($upSellProducts as $upSellProduct) {
            $id = $upSellProduct->getId();
            $sku = $upSellProduct->getStatus(); 
            $_productStock = $stockItem->get($id);
            echo  $_productStock->getQty(); echo '<br />';
            echo $_productStock->getMinQty(); echo '<br />';
            echo $_productStock->getMinSaleQty(); echo '<br />';
            echo $_productStock->getMaxSaleQty(); echo '<br />';
            echo $_productStock->getIsInStock(); echo '<br />';
        }
    }
}
```

Where **coreRegistry** is an instance of **\Magento\Framework\Registry**

Where **stockItem** is an instance of **\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository**

Comment: @sri Does this answer solve your problem?